# FFMPEG remote IP camera over RTSP h.264 format to HLS Localhost m3u8 format

Tags: java, http, ffmpeg, stream, rtsp

I'm trying to convert the remote IP camera over RTSP to a localhost HLS format so that I can display it in a UI. I'm using a java library that only supports HLS over HTTP not remote IP camera.

I'm under the impression FFMPEG can do this because I can write the HLS file just fine directly to my disc but when I change the target to something like http://localhost:8080/stream.m3u8 it cannot seem to connect to localhost.

Below is my attempted FFMPEG command (IP/User/Pass left off) but I know that it can at least connect and read the RTSP camera fine.

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://[Username]:[Password]@[IP]/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264 -rtsp_transport ffplay http://localhost:8080/media.m3u8
```

The error I'm getting back is Connection to tcp://localhost:8080 failed: Error number -138 occurred

I thought that ffmpeg could handle hosting the file on localhost itself. FFServer is deprecated and removed but according to documentation it can still kick up a server just fine

https://ffmpeg.org/index.html#ffserv

Comment: hi @macmeyers50, does this worked now?

Comment: @krishna I took a different approach and used a node library that spawned FFMPEG to convert to mpeg1. Feel free to take a look at node-rtsp-stream

Answer (score 0):

Solution in this case was to move on from the HLS format and take advantage of node libraries that do RTSP streaming. There are many, in the end I used node-rtsp-stream.